# Median Filter in R

Tags: r, filter, mean, median

I have number of points and i need to convert mean filter (as mentioned below) into median filter for smoothing the plot. Can anyone please guide me in this ?

```
# Mean Filter
smoothfilter <- function(feat, ntap) 
{
    ofeat <- feat                             # Actual data 
    nfeat <- length(feat)                     # Length of a actual data  
    nhtap <- floor(ntap / 2.0)                                                  

    sf <- feat[1:(nfeat-ntap+1)]              
    for (j in 2:ntap) {
        sf <- sf + feat[j:(nfeat-ntap+j)]       
    }

    sf <- sf / ntap
    ofeat[(nhtap+1):(nfeat-nhtap)] <- sf
    ofeat 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your desired output?

Comment: I just want to compare mean filter results with a median filter results. I have wrote a mean filter but i am confused about the median filter approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is two function for an average filter and a median filter :

```
mav <- function(x,n=5){filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=2)} #Average
mmed <- function(x,n=5){runmed(x,n)} #Median
```

Comment: I didn't know about `runmed`. My mind immediately went to `zoo::rollapply`.

Comment: What is n=5 in it ?

Comment: This is just the parameter of your filter set at 5 for its default value.

Comment: That means that if you don't put anything for n it will take n=5. That means that your filter is a moving average/median of order 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot Smich :)